# Chakra UI: Can't set custom font from Fontsource

Tags: javascript, typescript, chakra-ui, font-family

I installed a font from Fontsource called Girassol (https://fontsource.org/fonts/girassol) as so:

```
npm install @fontsource/girassol
```

I also have a `theme.ts` file which looks like this:

```
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const customTheme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Text: {
      variants: {
        logo: {
          bgGradient: "linear-gradient(45deg, #20b2aa, #cc0000)",
          textFillColor: "transparent",
          bgClip: "text",
          fontFamily: "Girassol, sans-serif",
          fontWeight: "800",
          as: "span"
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export default customTheme;
```

I then have a `Home.tsx` file which looks like this:

```
import { Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import "@fontsource/girassol"

export function Home() {
  return (
  <Text variant={"logo"} as={"span"}>
    Some Text
  </Text>
  );
}
```

However, I can't get the font to change to what I downloaded.  If I change the font in my `theme.ts` file to something more "standard" like Arial or Times New Roman, the font changes to match.  However, I can't seem to get the custom font to work...  Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Thanks,

Carolina

Comment: use `!important` or set the body's fontFamily in your `theme.ts` to `"Girassol, sans-serif"`, also put `import "@fontsource/girassol"` in the root file, eg: put it where you put your `ChakraProvider`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

I added `import "@fontsource/girassol"` to my `main.tsx` file (the file where I import my `ChakraProvider`).

After I did this, I started getting the exact same error as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74902697/error-the-request-url-is-outside-of-vite-serving-allow-list-after-git-init) post, which also helpfully explains what the error means.

I didn't follow the solution in the post however.  I simply realised that the `@fontsource` folder was in the wrong place.  It should be located with the `node_modules` folder of my local *repository* folder but instead it was just located in another `node_modules` folder outside of my repo.  So I just copy-pasted it to the right folder and it worked!